# Updating the existing row in a table with session data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entire class object stored in my session. I want to update an existing row in a table with the session data. I am trying to find out if their any better way. In the below code, I am trying to get the data from Session["MailingInfo"] and trying to update the data in the existing table. I tried to do this:

```
IDData = MI
```

That didn't work so I tried this way and it worked. I was wondering if there is any simple way to achieve this or do I need to assign each property individually like so:  `IdData.FirstName = MI.FirstName` and so on.

```
MailingInfo MI = (MailingInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["MailingInfo"];
using (IdentityProofContext dbContext = new IdentityProofContext())
{
    MailingInfo IdData = dbContext.MailingInfo.Where(r => r.MailId == mId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (IdData != null)
    {
        IdData.Compeletd = "Y";
        IdData.FirstName = MI.FirstName;
        IdData.MiddleName = MI.MiddleName;
        IdData.LastName = MI.LastName;
        IdData.StreetAddress = MI.StreetAddress;
        IdData.City = MI.City;
        IdData.State = MI.State;
        IdData.Zip = MI.Zip;
        IdData.PhoneNumber = MI.PhoneNumber;

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of mapping each field individually, you can use any ORM to map the class properties with the datatable. There are several ORM frameworks are available.

Comment: isn't entity framework and ORM? I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an object you are caching in Session State, one option is to simply re-associate it with the DbContext, make the updates, and save it.

```
MailingInfo IdData = (MailingInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["MailingInfo"];
using (IdentityProofContext dbContext = new IdentityProofContext())
{
    dbContext.Attach(IdData);
    IdData.Completed = "Y";

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the data in the MailingInfo had been potentially updated since it was read, such as by Ajax calls to update details (but ***not*** replacing the MailingInfo reference with a copy from the client) then you can mark the entity as modified prior to saving:

```
MailingInfo IdData = (MailingInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["MailingInfo"];
using (IdentityProofContext dbContext = new IdentityProofContext())
{
    dbContext.Attach(IdData);
    IdData.Completed = "Y";
    dbContext.Entity(IdData).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The important thing here is to only use this approach if you unconditionally *trust* the data. For instance if you have an Ajax call to update contact details where you accept a Info ID and the updated details, validate those, and update the session state copy of data, that is trustworthy. If you have an UpdateMailingInfo that accepts a copy of the entity back from the client and you replace the session state entity with that copy from the client, that is ***not*** trustworthy. A user/plugin could completely replace data in the serialized entity you get back, and using an approach like this would completely overwrite the data with potentially invalid/illegal values.

Arguably the safest way to set this up if you are passing entities around would be with Automapper. The typical use case for Automapper is projecting Entities to/from ViewModels, however you can leverage it to help control exactly what can be copied over from one disconnected copy of an entity to a "live" one. For instance using Automapper you can create a map for MailingInfo to MailingInfo and configure it to ignore properties you don't allow to be changed:

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<MailingInfo, MailingInfo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MailId, opt => opt.Ignore())); // Can add conditions to ignore overwriting values.

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

MailingInfo MI = (MailingInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["MailingInfo"];
using (IdentityProofContext dbContext = new IdentityProofContext())
{
    MailingInfo IdData = dbContext.MailingInfo.Where(r => r.MailId == mId).Single();
    mapper.Map(IdData, MI);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The premise here would be to configure the mapper to only copy across fields that are legal and ignore the rest. This gives you a one-liner to copy the fields from one copy of the entity to the data-linked one. The advantage of this over doing something like setting the EntityState is that the Update statement will only generate if any of the fields actually changed, and only for those modified fields. Where the EntityState change will update *all* fields whether they changed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.